# WebBrowser Issue with Late Bind object/property names

Tags: vb.net, browser, late-binding

There are issue with using WebBrowser late bind calls related to object/property names generation.

For example:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.Forms.Myform.mycontrol.Value = "test"
```

will fail with more than one instance of the WebBrowser control

what actually happen is that **mycontrol** object become **Mycontrol** and compiled vb.net application will fail with error

> Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))
>   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet(Object o, Type objType, 
>   String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack)
>   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, 
>   Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, 
>   Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
>   at Execute() in C:\Projects\WebBrowser\SampleCall.vb:line 16

Is there are any solutions for this issue?

Same code will work with vb6 app with multiple WebBrowser controls

Edit: This code is comipled with: Option Strict Off

Answer (score 2):

@bugtussle

Next assignments will work:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("Myform").Children("mycontrol").InnerText = "test"
WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.Forms("Myform").all("mycontrol").Value = "test"
WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument.Forms.Myform.all.mycontrol.Value = "test"
```

The problem with this approach that is required to change and retest a lot of code

If you take a look into Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.LateGet method using reflector utility, you can find that BindingFlags.IgnoreCase flag is used in binder.InvokeMember call.

I do undestant that this call is done through COM, and was reading somewhere that COM interop is using one version of name in a lookup table. Like if parameter name was initially entered into that table as "MyControl" than this version will be used, not "mycontrol". I think because of that later on InvokeMember is failing to find correct member.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value a different way:
`WebBrowser1.Document.Forms("Myform").children("mycontrol").Value = "test"`